# How can I display details of a computer's hardware in linux?

Tags: linux

How can I display information about a computer's hardware in linux? How could I display, for example, the amount of RAM, processor speed, HDD size, graphics card model etc.?

Is there a way to view hardware information from the command line?
Are there any other ways to see it?

Comment: Look for `lshw`.

Comment: Read the man page for `/proc`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `lshw` http://ezix.org/project/wiki/HardwareLiSter

Answer (score 1):

You may use **uname** command for getting basic system information .
Pl. see the manual page for all the options supported.

You may also browse the **proc file system** for getting more detailed information.

Pl. check the link below, to get learn more about proc file system.

http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-proc.html

Answer (score 1):

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
cat /proc/meminfo
lshw
lspci
lsusb
find /sys
```

...and more, depending on what you want.